# Installing OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to install OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.10 according to [instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).
I installed all mentioned dependencies, but when I'm trying to run `make` I get such errors:

```
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:114:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H261’ was not declared in this scope
 { CODEC_ID_H261, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '1') }
```

for all codecs, as I think.
And these errors:

```
    In file included from /home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘double CvCapture_FFMPEG::getProperty(int)’:
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:773:33: error: ‘AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
         return av_q2d(video_st->r_frame_rate);
                                 ^
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘double CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_fps()’:
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:820:49: error: ‘AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
     double fps = r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->r_frame_rate);
                                                 ^
In file included from /home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function ‘int icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, uint8_t*, uint32_t, AVFrame*)’:
/home/ilia/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1236:72: error: ‘avcodec_encode_video’ was not declared in this scope
         out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, picture);
                                                                        ^
```

It looks like it can not find some header files, but I installed all necessary dev packages
libswscale-dev, libavdevice-dev, libavfilter-dev, libavformat-dev, libavcodec-dev. What should I do to resolve these problems?

Comment: in Ubuntu 14.10, libav uses the API version 11.
OpenCV still uses API version 9, contained in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I think they have to provide a patch for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have special reasons I would suggest installing the OpenCV that are already in the Ubuntu repository: `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`

For video codecs I suggest simply trying to install all ffmpeg and gstreamer related codec packages.

Comment: Thank you. It was much easier than I thought.

Comment: well, that's not a solution. Especially if someone requires Qt, CUDA, OpenNI.

Answer (score 17):

Installing OpenCV from the Ubuntu repositories is a good choice for the most cases, but sometimes you need build OpenCV from sources yourself.

For example, if you need OpenCV's non-free functionality, or want to contribute to this project (you should use the latest version to create pull request), or want to change something (yes, OpenCV can also contain bugs).

Possible solution is building ffmpeg (it's rather simple) - I really don't understand why Debian/Ubuntu prefers libav without alternative.

For installing ffmpeg you should download its sources from [official site](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or clone GIT repository (git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git), then enter source directory and run

> ./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
>   make
>   sudo make install

you can also add other parameters to `configure`.
You can build static libraries too, but OpenCV can't be built with static ffmpeg libraries (now I don't know why).

After this you can download OpenCV sources from [OpenCV site](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) or clone GitHub repository ([OpenCV repository](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv)), create build folder and run from it the following:

> cmake PATH_TO_SOURCES -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
>   make
>   sudo make install

Of course, `PATH_TO_SOURCES` must be actual path to your OpenCV sources.

After these steps you have working latest OpenCV build in your system.

Comment: building ffmpeg from sources instead of using libav worked for me.

Comment: it's exactly what I suggested in my answer

Comment: I got this message: Is it ok to diable yasm? hyasm/nasm not found or too old. Use --disable-yasm for a crippled build. @avtomaton

Comment: @avtomaton UPDATE: i tried it but I got the same error . I am using mac os

Comment: @MAS possibly incompatible versions of opencv and ffmpeg. On Mac I prefer `brew` or `port` for installing ffmpeg instead of compiling from sources - should work with the latest opencv (3.1). If you prefer compiling from sources, please carefully check ffmpeg and opencv versions and their compatibility. Original question is relevant for ubuntu 14.10, where maintainers removed ffmpeg from repositories for the some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to build without a ffmpeg:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Without ffmpeg you will possibly get version without reading and writing video - it's OK only if you don't use them in your projects