# Installing Opencv in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I have tried almost all the blogs pertaining to the installation of OpenCv but I can't perform the make step.

I am getting the following problem

```
Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
In file included from /home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:65:0,
                 from /home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:98:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:99:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('h', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:100:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('X', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:101:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('x', '2', '6', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:102:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('a', 'v', 'c', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:103:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H264, MKTAG('V', 'S', 'S', 'H') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:105:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H263’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H263, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:106:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H263P’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H263P, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:107:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H263I’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H263I, MKTAG('I', '2', '6', '3') }, /* intel h263 */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:108:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H261’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H261, MKTAG('H', '2', '6', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:111:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H263P’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H263P, MKTAG('U', '2', '6', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:112:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H263P’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_H263P, MKTAG('v', 'i', 'v', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:114:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('F', 'M', 'P', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:115:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', 'X') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:116:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('D', 'X', '5', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:117:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('X', 'V', 'I', 'D') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:118:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('M', 'P', '4', 'S') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:119:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('M', '4', 'S', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:120:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG(0x04, 0, 0, 0) }, /* some broken avi use this */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:123:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:124:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('B', 'L', 'Z', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:125:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('m', 'p', '4', 'v') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:126:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('U', 'M', 'P', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:127:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('W', 'V', '1', 'F') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:128:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('S', 'E', 'D', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:130:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG4, MKTAG('R', 'M', 'P', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:132:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '3') }, /* default signature when using MSMPEG4 */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:133:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('M', 'P', '4', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:136:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('M', 'P', 'G', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:137:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '5') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:138:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '6') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:139:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:140:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('A', 'P', '4', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:141:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('C', 'O', 'L', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:142:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3, MKTAG('C', 'O', 'L', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:144:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2, MKTAG('M', 'P', '4', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:147:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2, MKTAG('D', 'I', 'V', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:149:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V1, MKTAG('M', 'P', 'G', '4') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:151:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_WMV1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_WMV1, MKTAG('W', 'M', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:154:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_WMV2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_WMV2, MKTAG('W', 'M', 'V', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:155:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO, MKTAG('d', 'v', 's', 'd') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:156:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO, MKTAG('d', 'v', 'h', 'd') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:157:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO, MKTAG('d', 'v', 's', 'l') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:158:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO, MKTAG('d', 'v', '2', '5') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:159:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO, MKTAG('m', 'p', 'g', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:160:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO, MKTAG('m', 'p', 'g', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:161:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO, MKTAG('m', 'p', 'g', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:162:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO, MKTAG('M', 'P', 'E', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:163:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO, MKTAG('P', 'I', 'M', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:164:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO, MKTAG('V', 'C', 'R', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:165:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO, 0x10000001 },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:166:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO, 0x10000002 },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:167:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO, MKTAG('D', 'V', 'R', ' ') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:168:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO, MKTAG('M', 'M', 'E', 'S') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:169:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:170:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('L', 'J', 'P', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:171:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_LJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_LJPEG, MKTAG('L', 'J', 'P', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:172:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('J', 'P', 'G', 'L') }, /* Pegasus lossless JPEG */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:173:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('M', 'J', 'L', 'S') }, /* JPEG-LS custom FOURCC for avi - decoder */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:174:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('j', 'p', 'e', 'g') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:175:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('I', 'J', 'P', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:176:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MJPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MJPEG, MKTAG('A', 'V', 'R', 'n') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:177:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV, MKTAG('H', 'F', 'Y', 'U') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:178:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF, MKTAG('F', 'F', 'V', 'H') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:179:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_CYUV’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_CYUV, MKTAG('C', 'Y', 'U', 'V') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:180:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, 0 },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:181:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('I', '4', '2', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:182:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('Y', 'U', 'Y', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:183:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('Y', '4', '2', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:184:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('Y', 'V', '1', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:185:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('U', 'Y', 'V', 'Y') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:186:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:187:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('Y', '8', '0', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:188:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO, MKTAG('H', 'D', 'Y', 'C') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:189:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_INDEO3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_INDEO3, MKTAG('I', 'V', '3', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:190:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_INDEO3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_INDEO3, MKTAG('I', 'V', '3', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:191:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP3, MKTAG('V', 'P', '3', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:192:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP3, MKTAG('V', 'P', '3', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:193:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_ASV1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_ASV1, MKTAG('A', 'S', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:194:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_ASV2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_ASV2, MKTAG('A', 'S', 'V', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:195:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VCR1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VCR1, MKTAG('V', 'C', 'R', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:196:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_FFV1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_FFV1, MKTAG('F', 'F', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:197:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_XAN_WC4’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_XAN_WC4, MKTAG('X', 'x', 'a', 'n') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:198:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSRLE’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSRLE, MKTAG('m', 'r', 'l', 'e') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:199:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSRLE’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSRLE, MKTAG(0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:200:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('M', 'S', 'V', 'C') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:201:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('m', 's', 'v', 'c') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:202:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('C', 'R', 'A', 'M') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:203:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('c', 'r', 'a', 'm') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:204:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('W', 'H', 'A', 'M') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:205:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1, MKTAG('w', 'h', 'a', 'm') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:206:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_CINEPAK’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_CINEPAK, MKTAG('c', 'v', 'i', 'd') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:207:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION1, MKTAG('D', 'U', 'C', 'K') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:208:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_MSZH’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_MSZH, MKTAG('M', 'S', 'Z', 'H') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:209:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_ZLIB’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_ZLIB, MKTAG('Z', 'L', 'I', 'B') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:210:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_SNOW’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_SNOW, MKTAG('S', 'N', 'O', 'W') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:211:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_4XM’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_4XM, MKTAG('4', 'X', 'M', 'V') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:212:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_FLV1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_FLV1, MKTAG('F', 'L', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:213:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_SVQ1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_SVQ1, MKTAG('s', 'v', 'q', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:214:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_TSCC’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_TSCC, MKTAG('t', 's', 'c', 'c') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:215:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_ULTI’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_ULTI, MKTAG('U', 'L', 'T', 'I') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:216:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VIXL’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VIXL, MKTAG('V', 'I', 'X', 'L') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:217:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_QPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_QPEG, MKTAG('Q', 'P', 'E', 'G') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:218:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_QPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_QPEG, MKTAG('Q', '1', '.', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:219:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_QPEG’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_QPEG, MKTAG('Q', '1', '.', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:220:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_WMV3’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_WMV3, MKTAG('W', 'M', 'V', '3') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:221:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_LOCO’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_LOCO, MKTAG('L', 'O', 'C', 'O') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:222:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_THEORA’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_THEORA, MKTAG('t', 'h', 'e', 'o') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:224:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_WNV1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_WNV1, MKTAG('W', 'N', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:225:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_AASC’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_AASC, MKTAG('A', 'A', 'S', 'C') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:226:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_INDEO2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_INDEO2, MKTAG('R', 'T', '2', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:227:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_FRAPS’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_FRAPS, MKTAG('F', 'P', 'S', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:228:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION2’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION2, MKTAG('T', 'M', '2', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:231:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_FLASHSV’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_FLASHSV, MKTAG('F', 'S', 'V', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:232:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_JPEGLS’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_JPEGLS,MKTAG('M', 'J', 'L', 'S') }, /* JPEG-LS custom FOURCC for avi - encoder */
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:233:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VC1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VC1, MKTAG('W', 'V', 'C', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:234:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VC1’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VC1, MKTAG('W', 'M', 'V', 'A') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:235:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_CSCD’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_CSCD, MKTAG('C', 'S', 'C', 'D') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:236:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_ZMBV’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_ZMBV, MKTAG('Z', 'M', 'B', 'V') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:237:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_KMVC’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_KMVC, MKTAG('K', 'M', 'V', 'C') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:240:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP5’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP5, MKTAG('V', 'P', '5', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:241:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP6’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP6, MKTAG('V', 'P', '6', '0') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:242:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP6’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP6, MKTAG('V', 'P', '6', '1') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:243:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP6’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP6, MKTAG('V', 'P', '6', '2') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:244:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VP6F’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VP6F, MKTAG('V', 'P', '6', 'F') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:245:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_JPEG2000’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_JPEG2000, MKTAG('M', 'J', '2', 'C') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:246:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_VMNC’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_VMNC, MKTAG('V', 'M', 'n', 'c') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:250:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_TARGA’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_TARGA, MKTAG('t', 'g', 'a', ' ') },
       ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:252:7: error: ‘CODEC_ID_NONE’ was not declared in this scope
     { CODEC_ID_NONE, 0 },
       ^
In file included from /home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘double CvCapture_FFMPEG::getProperty(int) const’:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:784:33: error: ‘AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
         return av_q2d(video_st->r_frame_rate);
                                 ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘double CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_fps() const’:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:831:49: error: ‘AVStream’ has no member named ‘r_frame_rate’
     double fps = r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->r_frame_rate);
                                                 ^
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function ‘AVStream* icv_add_video_stream_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVCodecID, int, int, int, double, int)’:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1220:24: error: ‘CODEC_ID_H264’ was not declared in this scope
     if (c->codec_id == CODEC_ID_H264) {
                        ^
In file included from /home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In function ‘int icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, uint8_t*, uint32_t, AVFrame*)’:
/home/aman/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1269:72: error: ‘avcodec_encode_video’ was not declared in this scope
         out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, picture);
                                                                        ^
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:169: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2452: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When installing the dependencies it was saying that `libtiff4-dev` can't be found so I followed the suggestion as it said to install `libtiff5-dev`

And similar was the problem with some other dependency `libxine-dev`
so I installed the given alternative `libxine2-dev`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: May I suggest you try installing the "cv2" python bindings as I found this to be far less of a headache on linux systems.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't use the existing OpenCV package that is in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: well.. how to install the exsisting OpenCV package and how to use them. can u give a link. of how to use it

Comment: See the answer by Kornel.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it fixes your problem. Also, be more concise in posting details in a question.

Comment: As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592577/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-14-10/27020828#27020828 states, installing ffmpeg from source first fixes this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because libav has changed API and removed some stuff it's still used in OpenCV. Ubuntu 14.10 uses libav API version 11 and OpenCV still uses API version 9.
The problem is that [CODEC_ID_](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp#L98)* was changed to [AV_CODEC_ID_](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce)*.

I would suggest installing the OpenCV that are already in the Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

p.s.:
you can read more about in [OpenCV DevZone](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3986)

Comment: well i used that syntax you mentioned
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
but can you tell me how to compile the program after doing so.
Or alternately can u provide mme a fix to that CODEC_ID problem if that is not a problem please ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Linux on my PC, so I suggest to use the latest stable version (2.4.10) instead of 3.0 beta (github). 
The following site can be a good starting point to install and test OpenCV and its dependencies: http://karytech.blogspot.hu/2012/05/opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204.html
The site gives a solution for installing OpenCV from the Ubuntu repositories and for building it from source also.

Comment: Installing from  Ubuntu repository won't install opencv latest version.  Today 2.4.10 is latest stable version, and the repository has 2.4.9.

Comment: @Kornel, do you think replacing CODEC_ID_ by AV_CODEC_ID_should do it?

Comment: @YoArgentino No it doesn't cut it. But according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27020828/87359), I compiled ffmpeg from source. And now opencv compiles fine.

Comment: @Kornel Honestly, I wouldn't recommend installing prebuilt packages for OpenCV. I had more problems than anything else when I did that in the past. The build from source using cmake for configuration is quite straightforward, especially on Unix systems, and allows to have control on what kind of features and optimizations you'll get.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile OpenCV without ffmpeg. You can disable ffmpeg by providing -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF with cmake.

Please refer the link below for more details,

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4940