# OpenCV in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I had `OpenCV` installed in my `Ubuntu` machine running `Ubuntu 16.10`. Recently I updated to the latest `Ubuntu 17.04` and `OpenCV` failed to work.

I am getting the following error.

```
ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install `libjasper`. With the command `sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev`

But I am getting the error `E: Unable to locate package libjasper-dev`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You could look up the package name with: `apt-cache search libjasper` or `apt-cache search jasper`

Comment: @eyllanesc The package doesnt seems to be available for Ubuntu 17.04. Please check this link.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjasper-dev

Answer (score 44):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8622

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev
```

References to 17.04 packages no longer work.

Comment: affirmed on lubuntu 17.10

Comment: not worked in Ubuntu 18.04 for me. I got 404 Not Found error for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages

Comment: worked in 18.04 for me when I tried to install opencv

Comment: `Ign:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages`
`Ign:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages`
`Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages`
`404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]`

Comment: is there any really working solution for this?

Answer (score 16):

Installing the `opencv` library from the repository worked for me.
Just both the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install opencv-data 
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

After installing that it worked as before. Previously I had build `opencv` myself. The one from the repository will work apparantely.

Comment: Rebuilding your opencv disabling jpeg2000 support would work as well. Building opencv is usually the most powerful way of installing it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592577/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-14-10?rq=1 (votes strongly converged to the "build it yourself" version)

Comment: tnx for this answer!

Comment: awesome :D. worked for me as well, after struggling for 2 hrs with other methods.

Answer (score 14):

libjasper-dev is not available for Ubuntu 17.04.

So you need to install the package from an earlier release. Try the following:

```
echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will add a new line to the sources.list file in /etc/apt. It will allow installation of packages from 16.10.

You should be able to install the missing package libjasper-dev now with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
```

Comment: Having the dependencies issues in version 17.xx, still a good try

Comment: This did not work on Ubuntu 18.04. The below answer does, however.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" ;
sudo apt update ;
sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev      works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse) after @sirop command performed

Comment: Try it with single quotes: `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main'`  or manually edit /etc/apt/sources.list .

Comment: 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' should be 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'

Comment: @sirop how do you manually edit /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the new and updated, built version of opencv and success

Answer (score 0):

Write this Down, it is really helpful,

```
echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```