# Unable to locate package libjasper-dev

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to install opencv in ubuntu 17.04 and I know that the jasper library is removed from ubuntu 17.04

what should I do to complete install opencv correctly ???

I tried used this two below command that showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484357/opencv-in-ubuntu-17-04) but it does not work

> sudo apt-get install opencv-data
>
> sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev

Answer (score 35):

Use these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev
```

This worked on my Ubuntu 18.04 after I replaced the double-quotes with single quotes. With the double quotes I was getting this error:

```
Error: need a single repository as argument
```

Comment: There should be an additional single quote before deb.

Answer (score 6):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488374/7087579)

You will be able to install the libjasper-dev from a previous release

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326450/5326336 - This answer is more updated(in the same post)

Comment: Instead of linking to an answer in another more or less identical question, please flag the question as duplicate. This answer doesn’t add any information, it is just a sign post. Flagging as duplicate is the right way to set up a sign post.

Answer (score 3):

Under Ubuntu18.04, if you directly `add-apt-repository` will encounter another GPG error.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: ...EXPKEYSIGhttps://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ...
```

You have to update the key

```
sudo apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Then you are now safe to install `libjasper-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
```

[Reference](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7866#issuecomment-586581740)

Comment: This helped me fixed the problem, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

To build the latest version of libjasper as package for Ubuntu do the following:

Download the Jasper source code from here: https://github.com/jasper-software/jasper/tree/version-2.0.25

Run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=2.0.25

unzip jasper-version-$VERSION.zip
cd jasper-version-$VERSION
mkdir compile

SOURCE_DIR=`pwd`
BUILD_DIR=compile
INSTALL_DIR=/usr
OPTIONS=

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -H$SOURCE_DIR -B$BUILD_DIR -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR $OPTIONS

cd compile
make clean all

cat >description-pak <<EOF
JasPer Image Processing/Coding Tool Kit
EOF

fakeroot checkinstall --fstrans --install=no --pkgname=libjasper --pkgversion=$VERSION --pkgrelease 1 --pkglicense="JasPer 2.0" \
         bash -c "make install" </dev/null

mv libjasper_$VERSION-1_amd64.deb ../..
cd ../..
rm -rf jasper-version-$VERSION
```

Result is a Debian package that can be installed using dpkg or apt.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution was tested on mendel(debian) with arm64 architecture. If this works for Ubuntu is not clear.

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo nano multistrap-main.list
```

Add there these two lines:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security main
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports impish main
```

save and exit. Then run:

```
sudo apt update
```

If there is a key missing use the following and run again update:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key>
```

Then install jasper:

```
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev
```

Finally remove or comment out the added repositories from multistrap-main.list.

Answer (score 0):

> Add the Repository to APT

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
```

> Run an advanced key server command

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

> Update the package manager

```
$ sudo apt update
```

> Install the libjasper-dev library

```
$ sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev
```