# Installing OpenCV for docker on raspberry Pi3

Tags: python, docker, opencv, raspberry-pi3

Recently I started working with Docker, I succeeded in building some images for the purpose of running my python script which uses OpenCV.

Now for the next step, I want to deploy these images on my Raspberry Pi3B+, but I failed in building them on the Pi. I've also tried pushing the image which I build successfully on my Ubuntu laptop then go on to Pi and pull the image to run container from it, but it didn't work either.

I found the reason is that all I did was trying to use a amd64 arch (my laptop) image on armv7 arch (my Pi) so that causes some kind of conflict.

I then tried some base images on Docker Hub which were created for armv7, for example: [arm32v7/python:3.6](https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/python), and here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.6

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade \
        && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
        python3-numpy \
        libblas-dev \
        liblapack-dev \
        python3-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        gfortran \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-scipy \
        && apt-get -y update \
        && apt-get -y install python3-h5py \
        libsm6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender-dev 


RUN pip3 install scipy \
                cython \
                keras \
                opencv-python \
                scikit-image 

COPY cut.py detect.py c9_0_04_46_23_0.jpg /opt/
COPY MODEL /opt/MODEL
RUN mkdir -p /opt/anh_cut


WORKDIR /opt/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "cut.py"]
```

An error occurred at OpenCV installation step:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python

I also tried to replace `pip config` with:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

which is a repository of precompiled packages for arm architecture, but the same problem still occurred.

Is there any way for me to work around this problem? If not, can I just cross compile OpenCV on my laptop then copy to Dockerfile ? It would be nice if I could have some document to follow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/, they  support python version 3.4, 3.5 and 3.7. Here's a quote (emphasis is mine) :

> **Support**
>
> Wheels provided support all Raspberry Pi models (Pi 4, Pi 3, Pi 2, Pi 1 and Pi Zero). Wheels are provided for Raspbian Jessie **(Python 3.4)**, Raspbian Stretch **(Python 3.5)** and Raspbian Buster **(Python 3.7)**. See each package's project page for information on available wheels.

---

Keeping your modified pip config, and changing the `FROM` clause in the Dockerfile by :

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-buster
```

might fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, ive been able to install opencv normally, but another problem came up, the import cv2 in my python script inside the container show error: **ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**. I did  some searching and found this answer <https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326450/10747627> but didnt quite work as well. Is there any chance that i can find the libjasper source code and install in through copying and install in Dockerfile?